# Google Map pop -up windows doesn't show anything inside it

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using PHP MYSQL on WordPress with Google Map API where the code retrieve data from the MYSQL database and display markers on the map based on the existing coordinates in the database. also it display a infowindow on click Listener.

the problem is that the infow window doesn't shows any data inside of it.

can anyone one tel me where is the error?

## code:

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP2
        */

        get_header();
  ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 600px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

     var map,currentPopup;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };




        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,

            map: map
          });

          var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: feature,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
        }



        var features = [
        <?php
          global $wpdb;
            $prependStr ="";
            foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT siteID, latitude, longitude FROM site_coordinates2", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
               $latitude = $row->latitude;
               $longitude = $row->longitude;
               $info = $row->siteID;
           echo $prependStr;
       ?>
{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),

}
<?php
$prependStr =",";
}
?>
        ];



        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {

          addMarker(feature);
        }
}



         </script>


  </body>
</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Can you take a look to your browser's development console and find out whether the map's API throwing any error? Also, try to resize your browser, if the map shows up, then you need to add some extra code to fix it.

Comment: There is a javascript error generated by your code: `InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string; and [object Object]`, because as @duncan observed, `feature` is not a string in this line `content: feature,`.  What content do you expect to appear in the infowindow?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, you've got an array of features that looks like:

```
features = [
  {position: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2)},
  {position: new google.maps.LatLng(3, 4)},
  // etc...
];
```

i.e. the array contains objects with just a `position` property. So you correctly refer to that when you do:

```
position: feature.position,
```

However when you try and set your infowindow content using:

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: feature,
    maxWidth: 300
})
```

That won't work, because the `content` property is meant to be a string, not a JS object.  You need to specify some text there. If you're just wanting to display the coordinates, you could do:

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: feature.position.toString(),
    maxWidth: 300
})
```

Comment: i want to display in the info window some info retrieved from the MYSQL database beside the coordinates 
 but when i add something under this line the map doesn't showed up 

`position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),`